# US-EU gas deal: has US offered particularly favorable conditions?

Tags: united-states, european-union, gas, energy-independence

One of the major results of the President Biden's latest visit to Europe is signing of the US-EU gas deal, aiming at reducing European dependence on the Russian gas exports: see, e.g., [EU signs US gas deal to curb reliance on Russia](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-60871601).

My understanding is that previously EU was reluctant to buy American gas due to its higher cost compared to other sources (notably the Russian supply) and the high cost of the infrastructure investment required for importing liquified gas.

The EU economy is already more than the US affected by the sanctions imposed on Russia, and this move is likely to add to this strain. *Has the US offered particularly beneficial conditions to ease this transition and thus share the burden?*

Comment: EU simply doesn't want to buy Russian gas anymore. American gas may now be the cheapest alternative.  But they probably also try to get Arabian gas. On the other hand this question should be easily answerable, if the details of the delivery contract are made public.

Comment: The US administration is probably not in a position to easily do that. Unlike in Russia, most energy companies in the US are not state controlled. It would take (domestically contentious) legislation to subsidize exports to the EU and even then there is possible WTO litigation related to such subsidies etc.

Comment: @Fizz I think many in the EU would prefer an accomodation with Russia (as they had preferred till recently), so rullying Europeans to move to a more expensive gas requires perhaps requires more than just pointing out the Russian threat.

Comment: If you watch Fox Business, you'd know many Republicans are arguing for the US to just increase overall oil & gas production (now with the added goal of fighting Russia) by removing some environmental limits, giving permits etc. Which is problematic for Biden administration's green/climate plan of reducing such production in the long run. But this is how a number of Republicans see the solution: reduce state-imposed limits, which would in turn increase production and lower prices for everyone.

Comment: @Fizz it would be also interesting to see how many of gas producers are Biden's/Democrat campaign donors. Hunter Biden, after all, was on the board of the Ukrainian gas holding, even if he did nothing wrong - it is now a taboo subject in the US, but European press keeps bringing it up.

Comment: Good question.  However keep in mind that supplying more US gas to the European market (from the historically fairly segregated US market) is likely to drive up gas prices domestically in the US.  What might be a good deal for US gas producers may not look so good for US politicians.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica do American gas priducers have something like OPEC to agree about the prices/amount of production?

Answer (score 5):

Probably no in terms of pricing, based what's been disclosed so far and how analysts [have](https://www.eenews.net/articles/bidens-lng-deal-with-europe-jolts-gas-critics/) interpreted that:

> U.S. producers and exporters are already on track to exceed White House expectations for exports to Europe. “But this is due to attractive pricing and a function of market trade rather than governmental negotiations or cooperation,” said Ruth Liao, LNG editor of the Americas for ICIS, a price reporting agency.
>
> Liao noted that U.S. export terminals are already running at very high rates and there is little room for immediate additional supply. The Calcasieu Pass LNG export project in Cameron Parish, La., will add to that capacity when it comes online in 2023.
>
> Meyer at API noted the careful wording of Friday’s U.S.-European Commission announcement. The reality, he said, is that the destinations of LNG cargoes are dictated and determined by the market.
>
> “We have to be realistic about the fact that neither the United States government [nor] the European Union have any real control over dictating where those cargoes go,” Meyer said.

What the US-EU deal on this [seems](https://www.politico.eu/article/joe-biden-us-gas-eu-where/) to have mostly entailed are political commitments to building more LNG terminals (first in the EU), which would in turn facilitate higher volumes. (Generally, such projects need a host of approvals, environmental etc., so that in itself is no small matter, politically.)

I'm not sure there's even much of an agreement on long-term LNG contracts; the EU was mostly opposed to those, [last month](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/should-europe-use-more-long-term-lng-contracts-2022-02-07/). It's also hard for the public to know the prices for those. E.g. the pricing details for the 11-year contract (from Nov 2021) between (France's) Engie and a Cheniere (Texas) [were not](https://www.spglobal.com/commodity-insights/en/market-insights/latest-news/lng/111121-cheniere-to-supply-lng-from-texas-export-facility-under-new-deal-with-frances-engie) publicly disclosed. It was however more recently disclosed (in March) that the contract has now been [extended](https://lngir.cheniere.com/news-events/press-releases/detail/242/cheniere-and-engie-increase-volume-and-extend-term-of-lng) for 20 years.